# ImageView overlaps with TextView in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using a RecyclerView and this is the code for activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.romin.apodbrowser.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And for the RecyclerView items this is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pubDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/link" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pubDate"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_image" />


<org.sufficientlysecure.htmltextview.HtmlTextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/image"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image"
    tools:text="Description" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/link"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title"
    tools:text="LINK" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Basically, there is the Title at the top, the link, and the pubDate. Then there is the image, and then the description. Besides the image (ImageView), all the others are TextViews.

The problem is that when I load an image from an RSS feed to the ImageView, and the thumbnail is gone, the ImageView overlaps with the description TextView. I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find any solution. I understand that the bitmap changes its size and not the ImageView, and most likely that's what's causing the overlap, but I can't find a way to fix it.

Thank you so much in advance.

Screenshot:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2eMA.jpg][1]

Comment: can you post an image to have an idea how and where it overlaps ?

Comment: @AalapPatel I edited the question to include a screenshot at the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following line from `description`:

```
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

This will effectively move the description view below the image. I have just tested it out and it is working.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your solution but the image now doesn't seem to adjust view bounds.It's position isn't in the middle with equal distance from the left and the right, although I set scaleType to fitStart and adjustViewBounds to true.

Comment: @hms I misread the XML. I'll try again. Your description is constrained to the bottom of the parent and to the bottom of the image. Is the image so tall that it is overlapping the description because the description has no where to go being squeezed between the image and the parent bottom? If that's the case, what do you want to happen? Can you post a screenshot to make things clearer?

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot at the end. I understand what you are saying, but doesn't the recyclerView change the size of the item dinamically to fit the content of each item? If not, what would you suggest as an alternative solution? @Cheticamp

Comment: @hms Try removing the bottom constraint on description.

Comment: @hms Definitely remove the bottom constraint on description. See the updated answer. Sorry for the back-and-forth, but this should solve your problem with this layout.

Comment: The layout is perfect with API 24, but when I test it on API 19 the problem is  the same. With your change now the description goes down and hides some lines at the bottom, based on the height of the image. 
For some reason the recyclerView isn't adjusting the height of the item dynamically to be enough for all its content, based on the changing ImageView. In API 24, the height of the item is changed based on the height of the updated ImageView, therefore this problem doesn't exist in that API. @Cheticamp

Comment: @hms When you say "hides some lines at the bottom" can scroll to see those lines? If so, what you are seeing may be just a difference in screen size. It looks like I expect using API 19 on an emulated Nexus S with API 19.

Comment: No I can't scroll inside the items, just the whole RecyclerView.

Comment: @hms Can you scroll the RecyclerVIew to see the part of the description that is cut off?